# Magento 2.3.5 load main product image to preload it

Tags: product-images, magento2.3.5-p1, image-url

i created a phtml file, called in the catalog_product_view.xml file (inside the **head.additional** reference block), where i want to preload the main product image, for Core Vitals purpose, for example:

```
<link rel="preload" as="image" href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($imageUrl) ?>"/>
```

where $imageUrl is:

```
$imageUrl = $block->getImageUrl();
```

But, the url (cached) of the product image is not retrieved. No errors, but, simply this:

```
<link rel="preload" as="image" href/>
```

So, how can i simply get in the correct way the main product image url (the main product image in the product page?)

Thanks, regards

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your phtml

```
<?php
    $_product = $block->getProduct();
    $imageUrl = $block->getImage($_product, 'product_base_image')->getImageUrl();
?>
<link rel="preload" as="image" href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($imageUrl) ?>"/>
```

I hope this works

Answer (score 0):

no, it does not work. I think it's because the code is executed at head level, so, the instance of the product is not created at that time?

Answer (score 0):

anybody found a solution to this? I think that a preload image in a product page of a Magento website is a critical improvement for SEO.

Answer (score 0):

Has anybody found a solution for this?

I repeat: Magento 2.3.5, i want to insert in the head section the preload of the product image in a product page.

The target is to improve the LCP for SEO purpose. I have already inserted the preload of the font and of the head image (logo) with very good results.

i created a phtml file, called in the catalog_product_view.xml file (inside the head.additional reference block), where i want to preload the main product image, for Core Vitals purpose, for example:

```
<link rel="preload" as="image" href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($imageUrl) ?>"/>
```

where $imageUrl is:

```
$imageUrl = $block->getImageUrl();
```

But, the url (cached) of the product image is not retrieved. No errors, but, simply this:

```
<link rel="preload" as="image" href/>
```

I think it's because the code is executed at head level, so, the instance of the product is not created at that time, maybe?

So, how can i simply get in the correct way the main product image url (the main product image in the product page?)

Thanks

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/207532)